# First UITableViewCell loads slowly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7

I have a UITableViewCell that contains only a UIWebView that displays CSS text. This is the only type of cell I display in my table. I set a reuse identifier to reuse cells based on their index path (ex. @"0_0" for the first message, @"0_1" for the second). Always, however, the first cell loads very slowly. After the first cell, the rest display instantly.

I have tried manually creating a cell with reuse identifier @"0_0" in viewDidLoad. That doesn't seem to affect the speed of display for the first cell. Any thoughts?

Comment: WebView IS the problem. It will always take time to load content. Your options are "preload it in bg when App is launched", or load all other cells and then allow first cell to update. Or get rid of webview and try to find another solution that would +- fit Your needs.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that all your cells are the same except for the content in the UIWebView. If that's the case then you should use the same cell reuse identifier to make loading quicker.

I believe the way you are currently creating and assigning identifiers does not help the performance of the app. Cell that are "the same" should have the same identifier so that iOS can reuse the cells and just change the content.

Please provide a code example of how you instantiate your cells, it would help out!

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell (without proper code and without knowing if you're using a storyboard or not) if you're actually reusing the cell. However, you should keep in mind how tableviews really work: only a bunch of cells (the visible ones plus 1 or 2) are really allocated into memory. When a cell goes offscreen, it gets moved and repositioned on the other hidden side of the table (ex: if you're scrolling the contents up, it gets moved on the bottom side ready to be scrolled in) and only it's content gets reloaded. This works only if you're using the correct reuse identifiers, otherwise the table view will keep on generating new cells until memory runs out.
In your case, I would expect a slow first cell load (since it's being allocated) followed by almost instant contents reload upon reusing during scrolling. However, as I said, I can't tell it for sure without some more details about your project configuration and without code.

Comment: I didn't add code because the question is intended to be very general. That slow first cell that you expect-- is there any way to make it not slow? I tried "pre-loading" it in viewDidLoad, but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Ok, but you should at least tell us if you're using a storyboard/Interface builder or you're coding it all. As others have told you, you should use a single reuse identifier if you have a single type of cell. How many webviews are we talking about? Without the correct reuse indentifiers you are loading them ALL simultaneously, and this could affect the whole slow loading.